# Placing an image over another image in HTML such that if we resize the base image the position of the top image should be also vary accordingly

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class ="bg" id ="2"> 
  <img class ="four" id ="window"> 
  <img class ="four" id ="door"> 
  <img class ="four" id ="clock"> 
  <img class ="four" id ="table"> 
</div>
```

The division contains a wall background and i need to place window,door,clock and table images over the wall image in particular segments. If i try to resize the window size then my segment size in which i have to place each item decreases but my items image size and position remains the same.. The following are the css

```
.bg {
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("wall.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#door {
    position: relative;
    height: 151px;
    width: 368.5px;
    top: 258px;
    left: 463px;
    background-image: url("door.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#window {
    position: relative;
    height: 140px;
    width: 422.5px;
    top: 434px;
    left: 434px;
    background-image: url("window.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#clock {
    position: relative;
    height: 130px;
    width: 259.5px;
    top: 265px;
    left: 855px;
    background-image: url("clock.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#table {
    position: relative;
    height: 140px;
    width: 259.5px;
    top: 436px;
    left: 162px;
    background-image: url("table.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: create a fiddle of it

Comment: @Rob if I understood the question correctly, the answer is just few lines away from the OP

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, a pen would be handy. But if I'm picking you up correctly you need to add in a background position rule. `background-position: center center;` or whatever position suits.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `left`, `top`, `width`, `height` in Pixels (`px`), you can also use `%` (0..100) or `em` (0..1) for the `img` elements which should be relative to the parent container.

https://jsfiddle.net/dk73mg3w/2/